# include typoscript with php

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to include a typoscript file via php?
Normally I would include typoscript with this:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/setup/1.ts">
```

But I want to do this just with php and not typoscript. Is that possible?

My Purpose: I want to dynamically load typoscript in my page

Comment: perhaps you can explain what you want to do. I guess there is a better way to do. You know TypoScript Conditions? Constants?

Comment: I dont know which typoscript file i want to include. So Conditions wont help me. I want to try to make an autoloader for typoscript files so the name of the file is dynamic

Comment: the way you try to go, is very unusual. Perhaps it is possible to go the TYPO3 way. But without knowing what you try to archive, nobody can help with an differnt way.

Comment: as i said.. i want to create a typoscript autoloader.. for example. I want to have a directory with filenames like 15.ts and if the page with the id 15 was called, then the autolaoder should include the typoscript 15.ts (or page-15.ts) automatically

Comment: Well, you could put than in one file and use TypoScript Condition [userFunc = user_check_what_to_use({$a_constant}, 1)] ... [end] so put everything in one file and use conditions to separat?

Comment: i would like to make it more dynamically.. so that i dont have to add code for each page. But if there is no other way, i have no other choice than use conditions..

Comment: sorry, but i never had the need for that what you describe. I never heard about. So i wonder which special case you have, that you need to write the whole template dynamic. Usually i only have some parts dynamic, which i can manage easy with conditions, stdWrap and if or TypoScript constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by invoking accordant functions at an early stage, e.g. in calling or delegating it in `ext_localconf.php`. For example, the [bookstrap package](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/ext_localconf.php) is loading TypoScript in PHP like this:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig(
    '<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY
    . '/Configuration/PageTS/Mod/Wizards/newContentElement.txt">'
);
```

Please consider, that TypoScript is cached before the actual front-end rendering starts. This means, that you should not modify TypoScript if you're plugin class or controller logic has been called already.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to return a value from the php function and use typoscript conditions for choosing the typoscript file.

Comment: i dont want to use conditions with php to check wether a typoscript file should be imported, i dont know the name of the typoscript file. i want to get the name of the typoscript file dynamically from php

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following (if I get you right):

```
$typoscriptFile  .= file_get_contents($someFile);

$parser  = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_TSparser');
$parser->parse($typoscriptFile);

$tsArray = $parser->setup;
```

I really don't know how well that will play with anything related to global typoscript though.

If you wanted a complete correct parse, you might be able to pull something like this off if you populated a fresh `t3lib_TStemplate` instance from `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl` and than ran the code above. Might work, never tried.